# Рисуем свою кнопку

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi+

Рисую свою кнопку так:

```
.....
static HWND button1;
case WM_CREATE: 
{
    button1 = CreateWindow(L"button", L"",
        WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_OWNERDRAW,
        5, 40, 30, 30, hwnd, (HMENU)10001, hinst, NULL);

    break;
}

case WM_DRAWITEM:
{
    lpdrawstLogon = (LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT)lParam; 

    if (lpdrawstLogon->hwndItem == button1)
    {
        Graphics g(lpdrawstLogon->hDC);
        g.SetPageUnit(UnitPixel);
        Pen p(Color::Black, 2);
        SolidBrush br(Color(100, 255, 0, 0));
        g.FillRectangle(&br, 5, 40, 30, 70);
    }
    break;
}
...
```

Под отладкой проверял, в блок WM_DRAWITEM я попадаю, все выполняется без ошибок, но, отрисовка не происходит. "Кнопка" как была серой, так и остается ей. А должна стать красной, так ведь? В чем моя проблема? Спасибо.

Comment: А вы возвращаете `TRUE`? И что это за прямоугольник? он в `lpdrawstLogon->rcItem` укладывается?

Comment: @VTT возвращал не true. А надо? По поводу прямоугольника. Это те самые координаты, которые я указывал в WM_PAINT, при создании кнопки. 
Я еще делал так: узнавал размеры кнопки, и их передавал в DrawRectangle

Comment: RECT rect;
GetWindowRect(button1, &rect);

Comment: GetWindowRect дают размеры в экранных координатах, [В документации написано](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775923(v=vs.85).aspx), что следует возвращать.

Comment: @VTT я так понимаю, rcItem - это как раз таки прямоугольник, размеры кнопки?

Comment: По-моему, проблема в том, что Вы в `g.FillRectangle(&br, 5, 40, 30, 70);` передаёте координаты кнопки. Попробуйте написать так -
 `g.FillRectangle(&br, 0, 0, 30, 70);`